# AWS EC2 metadata Invoke-RestMethod -uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have Windows EC2 and trying to fetch metadata

```
Invoke-RestMethod -uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/

Invoke-RestMethod : Unable to connect to the remote server
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

How can I see the the metadata of EC2 instance?

Comment: Possibly: [AWS EC2 Windows 10 can't access metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45116140/174777)

Answer (score 1):

running `InitializeInstance.ps1` on the EC2 instance fixed the problem