# EC2 http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data returns 404

Tags: amazon-web-services

Trying to fetch EC2 userdata from win EC2 instance

`http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data`

I get 404 - Not Found error

Comment: How are you using this? In a web browser? Perhaps: [AWS EC2 Windows 10 can't access metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45116140/174777)

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are experiencing that because you have no EC2 user-data attached

I conducted an experiment in my AWS Console. I launched two identical EC2 instances based an Ubuntu 18.04 image. However with one of the instances I attached user-data, the other I didn't

#### Instance WITH user-data

```
$ curl http://169.254.169.254/latest
dynamic
meta-data
user-data

$ curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data
(prints my specified user-data)
```

#### Instance WITHOUT user-data

```
$ curl http://169.254.169.254/latest
dynamic
meta-data
(notice the absence of user-data)

$ curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data
.... <title>404 - Not Found</title> ....
```

This answers the OPs questions, but not what John Bresnahan experienced

Comment: I can confirm this, had an instance without user data was getting 404 however the meta-data prefix working, created an identical instance with a bootstrap script and the API is working.

Answer (score 0):

You MUST use the "/" at the end for all URIs.

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data/
```

Alternatively, you can use the DNS record "instance-data" instead the IP. e.g.:

```
curl http://instance-data/latest/user-data/
```