# EC2 instance temporary creds from IAM role not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I have an EC2 instance that I have associated an IAM role to. The Role is called EC2_Role (very original) and when I perform the following in Powershell :

```
Get-EC2InstanceMetadata -Path "/iam/info"
```

I get nothing.  Just a new prompt after it runs.

The following python code :

```
class Boto3STSService():
def __init__(self):
    sts_connection = boto3.client('sts')
    assume_role_object = sts_connection.assume_role(RoleArn='arn:aws:iam::153621189007:role/EC2_Role', RoleSessionName='sds_mws_session', DurationSeconds=3600)
    self.credentials = assume_role_object['Credentials']
    print(self.credentials)

credentials = Boto3STSService()
```

says "NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials" which seems to bear out the nothing I get from powershell.

the role, `arn:aws:iam::<account>:role/EC2_Role`, shows an profile of `arn:aws:iam::<same account>:instance-profile/EC2_Role` and it has a policy of AmazonEC2FullAccess.

So why would I be unable to retrieve temporary credentials, or any info at all, from the IAM role associated with the instance?

The instance is windows server 2016.

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45095261/aws-ec2-windows-10-cant-access-metadata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/EC2_Role/
```

I'm not sure how that translates to `Get-EC2InstanceMetadata`.

Comment: gives page not found.

Comment: In that case, start removing elements from the end until you get a valid response. It will provide a list of valid values.