# IAM Role not used by EC2 even if correctly applied after an EC2 cloning

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I cloned an EC2 (creating an image from that existing EC2, then launching an instance from that image).
I did that to move an EC2 from an availability zone to another one.
The config looks exactly the same, and the IAM role is properly assigned when I check the console.

Everything looks fine except that I the IAM role is not assumed by the EC2...
When I type "aws sts get-caller-identity" I get the correct result, but if I do the same from the new EC2 I get :

> C:\>aws sts get-caller-identity
>
> Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running
> "aws configure".

What am I missing ?
I already tried:

- unassign the IAM role then reassign it
- create a new role + instance profile then assign it
- reboot the instance

I also realized that in the old image, I can do
`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials`

On the new image I can't:
`curl: (28) Failed to connect to 169.254.169.254 port 80 after 21226 ms: Couldn't connect to servercurl: (28) Failed to connect to 169.254.169.254 port 80 after 21226 ms: Couldn't connect to server`

---

I finally found the reason.
Doing a `route print` I realized that AWS added some persistant routes to 168.254.169.xxx but the gateway was still the one from the previous availability zone.

It has been fixed doing:

```
route delete 169.254.169.123 
route delete 169.254.169.249 
route delete 169.254.169.250
route delete 169.254.169.251
route delete 169.254.169.253
route delete 169.254.169.254


route add 169.254.169.123 mask 255.255.255.255 <your-gateway>  metric 15 if 6 -p
route add 169.254.169.249 mask 255.255.255.255 <your-gateway>  metric 15 if 6 -p
route add 169.254.169.250 mask 255.255.255.255 <your-gateway>  metric 15 if 6 -p
route add 169.254.169.251 mask 255.255.255.255 <your-gateway>  metric 30 if 6 -p
route add 169.254.169.253 mask 255.255.255.255 <your-gateway>  metric 30 if 6 -p
route add 169.254.169.254 mask 255.255.255.255 <your-gateway>  metric 30 if 6 -p
```

`6` here being the network interface listed at the beggining of route print command.

Comment: The reason that curl fails is also why the awscli cannot retrieve credentials. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45095261/aws-ec2-windows-10-cant-access-metadata) as you may need to reset cached settings on the instance. If that's not it, do you have any non-default firewall rules or security software on this Windows EC2 instance?

Comment: Thank you, AWS should add this information to this page:
https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/move-ec2-instance

Comment: Yes, probably a good idea. I think you can comment on re:Post pages.